# How to run Different congestion control algorithms in FEDORA 17?

Tags: tcp, linux-networking, kernel-modules, fedora

I need to use different congestion control algorithms for tcp flow.

How can I continue using those flow congestion algorithms from Fedora 11 in Fedora 17?

Comment: Don't change the congestion control algorithm unless you _really know what you're doing_.

Comment: I suspect you will probably need to recompile your kernel and enable those features.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `kernel-modules-extra` package to get these modules.

Comment: Not on Fedora 22 it seems. That was also my reflex, but after installing it, only DCTCP is available as a module, the others (which are compiled as modules by Fedora, e.g. YEAH, LP TCP, SCALABLE TCP, etc.) are not installed with this package.

Answer (score 0):

You can run different congestion control using this command. I.e Congstion Control Algorithm name

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=cubic
```